# How do I delete/replace all single, double quotes and semicolons from the Array values

Tags: php, mysql

```
$data= array();
$data[1]= Trial" Broker;
$data[2]= some'y Bank .
$data[3]=United ;States
```

My array contains lots of single, double quotes and semicolons in between the value and I don't want them.

This might help: replace them is enough.

I'm looking for the simplest function to perform this task please.

Comment: will you pay me for that ? ;)

Comment: sorry am a beginner can you help me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: @Subashini Dharmalingam take a look at my example in the answer as this is what your looking for.

Comment: i will try and reply you soon sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the array and do a simple preg replace to strip out all characters other than a-z and 0-9

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    $data[$i] = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9?!]/", "", $data[$i]);
}
```

Be sure to set $i to the starting number of your array within the for loop above

```
$i=1; // in your given example

$i=0; // usually by default an array will start from 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
array_walk(
    $data,
    function(&$element)
    {
        $element = preg_replace("/['\";]/", '', $element);
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks your code is absolutely fine and i learned a lot from it